# How to prevent arrayformula from filling in empty rows (Google Sheets/Excel)

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, google-sheets, nested-if

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **Apples** | **Bananas** | **Fruit** |
| 2 | 26 | 28 | Banana |
| 3 | 36 | 34 | Apple |
| 4 | 33 | 39 | Banana |
| 5 |  |  | Banana |
| 6 |  |  | Banana |

(Google Sheets) So over here I'm using arrayformula, on C1, to evaluate which type of fruit is larger in quantity.

The formula in C1: `=arrayformula( { "Fruit"; if(A2:A>B2:B, "Apple", "Banana") } )`

However, the rows starting from row 5 is filled up even though there isn't any input in the Apples and Bananas columns. Is there any way I could rewrite the formula in C1 such that these rows appear as blank? Also, due to the nature of the task, the `=arrayformula` function can't be removed. Appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: In general, it highly depends on the query / formula. Here is a nice article describing multiple cases https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/remove-extra-blank-cells-in-arrayformula-output/  (not mine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add another `IF` like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Fruit"; IF(A2:A="",, IF(A2:A>B2:B, "Apple", "Banana"))})
```